# How to make tab active using URL hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, tabs

I want to be able to send users a link that includes a hash that will open a specific tab on that link's page.

However, no matter which hash I place in the URL, that tab is never selected.  Clicking the tab buttons work just fine, though.

How can I make a tab active simply by grabbing the hash from the URL?

This is my partial code:

```html
<script>
$('.userhref').click(function(){
    $('#nav').find('li').find('a[href=' + $(this).attr('href') + ']').closest('li').addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
});
</script>

<div class="tabbable nav-tabs-container" style="max-width:1000px;">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav" name="tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Description</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Specs</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The full code and working example can be seen here:

https://www.s22.us/tabs.php#tab3

None of the solutions I've found work in this scenario.

Comment: [`:target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:target), [`hash`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Location/hash), [How to read the #hash (or fragment identifier) of the current page URL?](/q/15741421/4642212). _“None of the solutions I've found work in this scenario.”_ — Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: What code are you using to read the fragment from the URL and set the active tab? You've only posted the HTML

Comment: I also included a URL to a working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the appropriate tab based on `location.hash` and trigger a click on it on page load as well as the `hashchange` event.

```js
function changeTab() {
    $(`a[role=tab][href='${location.hash}']`).click();
}
changeTab();
window.addEventListener('hashchange', changeTab);
```

Comment: This works, but only if I manually refresh the window.  Using `location.reload();` does nothing.  Is there a way to make this work the first time?

Comment: @FrankJance I've updated my answer. Place this script right before the closing body tag.